# Build android framework resources

Tags: android, android-resources, android-framework

I'm trying to build a custom Android image from the Open Source repo, and make changes inside the android base framework code (both resource and Java code changes), and I have a couple of questions about how to build my changes without having to clean and rebuild the whole system.

My understanding of it, was that I could just do `mmm frameworks/base` after making my changes, and that would automatically rebuild the `framework-res.apk` and framework.jar in `out/target/product/<my-config>/system/framework/`.

But it looks like `mmm frameworks/base` doesn't do anything. I have to manually do `mmm frameworks/base/core/res` in order for the `framework-res.apk` to be compiled and then redo `mmm frameworks/base` to recompile the JAR.

Is that normal? Why doesn't `mmm`frameworks/base`recompile everything? Plus, the`/out/target/common/R/com/android/internal/R.java`file that is used by Eclipse to locate the resources is never re-generated unless I do a whole`make clobber; make`which takes forever. How can I simply re-generate the`R.java` file.

Additional question:
I wanted to add some third-party APKs to my ROM, I placed them in `/vendor/<vendor-name>/` along with a `Android.mk` file that I include from my main mk script. The apks are copied over to `/out/target/product/<my-config>/system/app`, but are not included in the `system.img` image. Why is that?

Comment: That's normal behaviour. Sometimes you only want frameworks/base/services/java to be compiled so I compile it on its own. Use  "mmm frameworks/base/core/res snod" if you don't want to run the command twice.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you:[Building, running & debugging Android source](http://devtcg.blogspot.in/2009/03/building-running-and-debugging-android.html)